# Run docker with just copied file inside

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm building an image that just contains a copied file, with the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.8

COPY ./somefile /srv/somefile
```

When I try to `docker run` the image, it exits immediately, that is just after `docker run` I have:

```
Exited (0) 1 second ago.
```

I tried adding `CMD ["/bin/sh"]` or `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"]` but it doesn't change anything.

Is it possible to have such container with just copied file and make it up and running, until I stop it?

Comment: What exactly should the container do? If your file is an application then your cmd should point to it.

Comment: `docker run -it your_image sh`

Comment: @tkausl it's just a container with data. I need it to have the data to connect with another container via `docker-compose`

Comment: You’re asking “how do I run a text file”, and that fundamentally doesn’t make sense.  Look at using Docker volumes or host-directory bind mounts to inject data around, especially for single files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is really no problem - you **have succeeded** running your docker with file inside. But as long as you didn't supply any additional job for your container, your run process had taken 1 second.

First you should get acquainted with what is considered as "running" container in Docker terminology. Container is "running" until its main process (`PID 1`) is running. Process exits => container stops. When you want your container to remain running (as a service for example), you need to keep your main process active.

Second, what is your main process? It is the process being launched upon container start. It is combined from `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` directives (with some rules). These directives are often given the default value in `Dockerfile` but you can override them. If you just run `docker run <image>`, default values are taken, but if you provide some arguments after `<image>`, they override `CMD`.

So, for `alpine` you can simply run shell like `docker run -it alpine sh`. And until you exit the shell, your container is running.

And the last. Argument `-it` connects both `STDIN` and `STDOUT/STDERR` to your console. So your `sh` process, which is main, keeps alive till you close the console.